# C++11: standard ref for constexpr member of template specialization needing extra declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following C++11 program produces an undefined reference to `S<42>::s` error in both gcc and clang...

```
#include <iostream>

template<int i> struct S;

template<> struct S<42> { static constexpr char s[] = "foo"; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << S<42>::s << std::endl;
}
```

By adding the following extra declaration ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char)) to the program...

```
constexpr char S<42>::s[];
```

...it suppresses the error, and the program compiles.

Where in the standard does it specify that a program without that extra declaration is ill-formed?  Which rules are in play here exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§ 9.4.2/3:

> A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.**

[emphasis added]

It looks to me like when you print out the value in `main` that's an odr-use, so the compilers are right: the definition is required.