# constexpr static data member giving undefined reference error

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a kernel and I want to make my static data member `constexpr` so I can have its values in an `enum class`. However, if I do so I get an undefined reference error. It only seems to work if I make it non-constexpr and initialize it outside of the class.

Working:

```
// terminal.hpp
class Terminal
{
    static uint32_t col_map[16];
};

// terminal.cpp
uint32_t Terminal::col_map[16] = {
    0x000000, 0x0000AA, 0x00AA00, 0x00AAAA,
    0xAA0000, 0xAA00AA, 0xAA5500, 0xAAAAAA,
    0x555555, 0x5555FF, 0x55FF55, 0x55FFFF,
    0xFF5555, 0xFF55FF, 0xFFFF55, 0xFFFFFF
};
```

Not working:

```
// terminal.hpp
class Terminal
{
    constexpr static uint32_t col_map[16] = {
        0x000000, 0x0000AA, 0x00AA00, 0x00AAAA,
        0xAA0000, 0xAA00AA, 0xAA5500, 0xAAAAAA,
        0x555555, 0x5555FF, 0x55FF55, 0x55FFFF,
        0xFF5555, 0xFF55FF, 0xFFFF55, 0xFFFFFF
    };

    enum class Color : uint32_t
    {
        Black = col_map[0],
        White = col_map[15]
    };  
};
```

Note that I tried to reproduce this on a regular compiler unsuccessfully so I think it has something to do with the kernel or cross compiler.

Linker error:

```
terminal.o: In function `Terminal::drawcolormap()':
terminal.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `Terminal::col_map'
```

I always run `make clean; make`.

Comment: What is the exact error message, and did you clean before building?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: [Undefined reference to static constexpr char\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016780/1708801)

Answer (score 7):

A static data member shall be defined outside the class if it is odr-used---*period*. There are no exceptions to this rule.

In the case that the data member is `constexpr`, it must also be initialized *inside* the class definition. However this does not abrogate the requirement to *define* it outside the class.

Correct code:

```
class Terminal
{
    constexpr static uint32_t col_map[16] = { /* ... */ };
    // ...
};
constexpr uint32_t Terminal::col_map[16]; // definition
```

It's counterintuitive, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: Actually that's not so counterintuitive, you are allowed to obtain the address of a variable contained in the array so you must provide a source file which can actually hold the static data.