# uniform initialization of static constexpr member

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, constexpr, uniform-initialization

According to:
[constexpr static data member giving undefined reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830111/constexpr-static-data-member-giving-undefined-reference-error)
static constexpr class members must meet two requirements:

```
template <typename Tp>
struct wrapper {
  static constexpr Tp value{}; // 1
};

template<typename Tp>
constexpr Tp wrapper<Tp>::value; // 2 

struct foo {
};

int main() {
  auto const& x = wrapper<foo>::value;
  (void)x;    
}
```

1. Initialized inside the class definition (because it is constexpr)
2. Defined outside the class definition (because it is static)

If I change 1. to uniform initialization

```
template <typename Tp>
struct wrapper {
  static constexpr auto value = Tp{}; // uniform initialization
};

template<typename Tp>
constexpr Tp wrapper<Tp>::value;
```

compiler complains about conflicting declarations:

```
$ g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1z -pedantic
prog.cc:7:31: error: conflicting declaration 'constexpr const Tp wrapper<Tp>::value' constexpr Tp wrapper<Tp>::value;
prog.cc:3:29: note: previous declaration as 'constexpr const auto wrapper<Tp>::value' static constexpr auto value = Tp{};
```

and also about missing initializer:

```
prog.cc:7:31: error: declaration of 'constexpr const auto wrapper<Tp>::value' has no initializer
```

Removing conflicting 2. definition ends, as expected, with linker error:

```
In function `main': prog.cc:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `wrapper<foo>::value'
```

Code example [online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mNBVAw3TuS6Gi8js).

Is it possible/legal to use uniform initialization for static constexpr class members?

Comment: This has something to do with the template parameter: It works as expected if the type of the static data member is not dependent on the template parameter, like `static constexpr auto value = int{};`

Comment: this wrapper class is actually a replacement for c++14 variable template in gcc < 5.0, so template parameter is a must

Comment: Do you need to use `auto`?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour `auto` is just part of uniform initialization, otherwise its like in original example `static constexpr Tp value{};`

Answer (score 1):

This may be my misunderstanding, but I would have regarded

```
struct wrapper {
    static constexpr Tp value = Tp{};
};
```

to be an example of uniform initialisation. Indeed, the first code example is also uniform initialisation. The standard itself just demands that these static constexpr members be initialised with a brace-or-assignment expression. This, as you've already seen, works fine.

The problem seems to be with the type deduction from `auto` in a template context, and I suspect it is an implementation bug, though the standard is big, and I could easily have missed something.

If the right hand size of the constexpr initialisation were an expression with a hard to pre-determine type, a workaround would be to use `decltype`, e.g.

```
template <typename Tp>
struct wrapper {
    static constexpr decltype(complex-init-expr) value = complex-init-expr;
};

template <typename Tp>
static constexpr decltype(complex-init-expr) wrapper<Tp>::value;
```

or

```
template <typename Tp>
struct wrapper {
    typedef decltype(complex-init-expr) value_type;
    static constexpr value_type value = complex-init-expr;
};

template <typename Tp>
static constexpr typename wrapper<Tp>::value_type wrapper<Tp>::value;
```

Comment: Do you think GCC 4.8.5 has a bug in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345310/conflicting-declaration-using-constexpr-and-auto-in-c11 ?

Comment: I believe so, but given that this sort of behaviour seems present across so many gcc versions, and for the example in this quesation, clang as well, I am not confident in my interpretation at all.

Comment: that's so weird