# Conflicting declaration using constexpr and auto in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, constexpr, auto

I'm experimenting with C++11, constexpr and auto.

I'm failing to understand why this code does not compile:

```
  template<class T, T t>
  struct TestEle2
    {

    };

template<class T, T t>
  struct DStruct {int a;};

  template<char t>
  struct TestEle2<char, t>
    {
    static constexpr auto f = 5;

    static constexpr auto g = &DStruct<char, t>::a;
    };

  template<char c>
  constexpr decltype(TestEle2<char, c>::f)
    TestEle2<char, c>::f ; // This compiles

  template<char c>
  constexpr decltype(TestEle2<char, c>::g)
    TestEle2<char, c>::g ; // This does not compile
```

Without definition I have linking problems. I know this problem has been fixed in C++17 but better understand fully C++11 now

[Edit]
Error message is:

```
error: conflicting declaration ‘constexpr decltype (TestEle2<char, t>::g) TestEle2<char, t>::g’
         TestEle2<char, c>::g ;
                            ^
error: ‘TestEle2<char, t>::g’ has a previous declaration as ‘constexpr const auto TestEle2<char, t>::g’
         static constexpr auto g = &DStruct<char, t>::a;
                               ^
error: declaration of ‘constexpr const auto TestEle2<char, t>::g’ outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]
```

[Edit 2]
I'm using GCC 4.8.5

Comment: When compilation fails, there is usually a diagnostic message. Did you not get any?

Comment: First you have a typo, should be `::g`, not `::f`.

Comment: The tuple is also a red-herring, can you remove all the non required code?

Comment: This is related to the template aspect of `DStruct`. Not sure why.

Comment: Clang fails in both cases, gcc works for only the second (MSVC doesn't care...)

Comment: I've removed the tuple and cleaned the code as you suggested

Comment: bug in the compilers perhaps?

Comment: To people closing as "why isn't this code not working", this is a valid [mcve] and a valid question.

Comment: @svoltron:  Looks like a bug. Works well with MSVS. Using `int*` instead of `auto` works. Is that not an option for you?

Comment: yep I've noticed it works without auto. Unfortunately I'll be using tuples with complex types so auto it is a must..

Comment: @svoltron: See this bug report. [compilation error with constexpr in template types with redeclared methods](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69837). And also this one: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69836

Comment: it seems similar to my problem.. damn, I need to find a workaround then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following a long comment instead of an answer (sorry).

I don't know who is right (MSVS that accept all, g++ that accept `f` but refuse `g` or clang++ that refuse both `f` and `g`) but, if I understand correctly, this is a simplification of a more complex problem that you can't solve simply using `int` and `int *` instead of `auto`.

So I propose to insert a couple of types inside `TestEle2`

```
using typeF = decltype(5);
using typeG = decltype(&DStruct<char, t>::a);
```

and use them instead of `auto` and `decltype()` for `f` and `g` types.

The following is a full compiling (both g++ and c++; I don't know MSVS (sorry)) example

```
template <class T, T t>
struct TestEle2
 { };

template <class T, T t>
struct DStruct
 { int a; };

template <char t>
struct TestEle2<char, t>
 {
   using typeF = decltype(5);
   using typeG = decltype(&DStruct<char, t>::a);

   static constexpr typeF f = 5;
   static constexpr typeG g = &DStruct<char, t>::a;
 };

// This compiles
template <char c>
constexpr typename TestEle2<char, c>::typeF TestEle2<char, c>::f; 

// This also compile
template <char c>
constexpr typename TestEle2<char, c>::typeG TestEle2<char, c>::g;

int main()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Very good solution, I'm gonna look into it. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @svoltron - But not an answer to your question; I suspect you have an egg and chicken problem and I'm not a language lawyer so I don't know which compiler is correct. But defining before, with `using` or `typedef`, the types should break the egg and chicken problem.

Comment: I think you're right. If it really is a GCC bug I need a workaround, and the one you proposed seems a good one. The only contra is the code repetition I think