# Undefined reference to static constexpr string (except if it's a pointer)

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constexpr

This work:

```
template<typename T> struct Something
{ static constexpr const char* str = "int"; };

int main()
{ std::cout << Something<int>::str << std::endl; }
```

But it doesn't:

```
template<typename T> struct Something
{ static constexpr const char str[] = "int"; };

int main()
{ std::cout << Something<int>::str << std::endl; }
```

`gcc-4.8` says: "undefined reference to `Something<int>::str`".

This error can be solved defining the static member outside of the class:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr const char Something<T>::name[];
```

Why isn't it neccesary with pointers but with arrays? Both are `static constexpr` members after all.

Comment: See also: [Undefined reference to static constexpr char\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016780/1708801)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An object or function must be defined if it is odr-used. In some cases objects and functions are not odr-used and in those cases you don't have to define them. Whether or not the declaration of a static class member has an initializer, it is still not a definition. In all cases the rule is that an out-of-class definition at an enclosing namespace scope is required if the static member is odr-used.

The intuition is that "odr-used" means "the linker needs its address". If a `constexpr` variable is only used in ways that require its value---and never its address---then it may avoid being odr-used. In such cases the compiler simply inlines its value, and it does not need to be defined, because the linker doesn't need its address. That's the case with `const char* Something<int>::str`, but not `const char Something<int>::str[]`.

"But they're the same!", you shout. Not so. For when `str` is a `const char*`, its **value** is the **address** of the string literal `"int"`. The address of the string literal is needed, but not the address of `str` itself. The former is the value of `str` and it satisfies the requirements for *not* being odr-used; the compiler can just inline it. But when `str` is a `const char[]`, its **value** is the string literal `"int"` itself. When you try to output it using `istream::operator<<`, it is implicitly converted into a `const char*`. But the `const char*`'s **value** is the **address** of the string literal, that is, the address of `Something<int>::str`. Therefore in this case `Something<int>::str` is odr-used; its address is needed.

There is logic in the standard that can be used to determine precisely when a variable is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]). But I'm not going to quote it because it's the most confusing section of the entire standard. I will say that in the case where you have `const char* Something<int>::str`, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied, which is one of the conditions for it to not be odr-used; and in the case where you have `const char Something<int>::str[]`, the array-to-pointer conversion is immediately applied, and that doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: Wow, the only things your answer is (intentionally) missing are what is in mine.

Answer (score 3):

N3485, §3.2 [basic.def.odr]/3 says:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   ex is odr-used unless x is an object that satisfies the requirements
>   for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and ex is an element of
>   the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

In the case of the array, it must undergo an array-to-pointer conversion in order to fit the overload set of `operator<<`. This is not listed in the above text, and so the array `str` is odr-used.

§9.4.2 [class.static.data]/3 says (emphasis mine):

> A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class
>   definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall
>   specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause
>   that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In
>   both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. — end
>   note ] **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   odr-used (3.2) in the program** and the namespace scope definition shall
>   not contain an initializer.

Since the array `str` is odr-used, it must be defined outside of the class. The pointer `str` is not odr-used, and thus does not have to be.