# Linking against a shared library with explicitly instantiated templates

Tags: c++, templates, cmake, linker

I am building a shared library that instantiates some template code. This template code uses other templates (traits). In the corresponding .cpp I explicitly instantiate the templates that I want to use from that shared library.

After this, I link against this library and I use those instantiated functions, but I get a linker error.

Sample code:

include/shared.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "otro.hpp"

template<class T>
void tal(){
    std::cout << f<T, int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

include/otro.hpp

```
template<class T, class U>
struct f{};

template<class U>
struct f<int, U>{
    static constexpr char value[] = "chars";
};
```

src/shared.cpp

```
#include "shared.hpp"
template void tal<int>();
```

src/main.cpp

```
#include "shared.hpp"
int main(){
    tal<int>();
}
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED shared.cpp)
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Remark: If I change the type of the trait `f` to `int` it works perfectly well.

Comment: Can you show the link error please.

Comment: `main.cpp:(.text._Z3talIiEvv[_Z3talIiEvv]+0x5): undefined reference to f<int, int>::value`

Comment: Ok, I just found the solution here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char

I was not declaring the static member!