# Initialisation of static members in traits

Tags: c++, templates, static, traits

I have always read that you can define a trait like

```
enum MyEnum { val_1, val_2, val_3 };

template< typename T > 
struct my_trait { 
  static const MyEnum value = MyEnum::val_1;
};
```

and then specialise it

```
template<> 
struct my_trait < void >{ 
  static const MyEnum value = val_3; 
};
```

When I have tried it I always get a linker error since the `static` member is not defined, so I have to explicitly specialise it in the source file as

```
MyEnum my_trait < void >::value = val_3;
```

and change the definition in the header to

```
template<> 
struct is_void< void >{ 
  static const MyEnum value; 
};
```

Is there any way to define the trait directly in the header without having to redefine it in the header?

Comment: It doesn't have to be defined if it isn't odr-used. AFAICR, you're not supposed to odr-use the standard `::value`s.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "one definition rule"-used?

Comment: @Lezkus "odr-used" is a term in the standard. Nuances aside, it means "the object itself rather than its value is used." Such as bound to a reference or having its address taken.

Comment: Are you *really* getting this error for `bool`s?

Comment: If you want a full definition of odr-used, the standard or cppreference is your best bet honestly. But most sensible uses of traits don't do it. It's also worth pointing out that C++17 has inline variables and `static constexpr bool value = ...;` is implicitly inline.

Comment: @Angew I edited the question with the actual use case. I thought that they were equivalent, but I guess they are not.

Comment: May be `MyEnum GetMyEnumValue<int>()` will help?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer too? Some code which uses the trait and reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question but... in your example (if you can use a C++11 compliler) you can use `std::integral_constant`.

A full example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum MyEnum { val_1, val_2, val_3 };

template< typename T > 
struct my_trait : public std::integral_constant<MyEnum, MyEnum::val_1>
 { };

template<> 
struct my_trait<void> : public std::integral_constant<MyEnum, MyEnum::val_3>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << my_trait<void>::value << std::endl; // print 2 (aka val_3)
   std::cout << my_trait<int>::value << std::endl;  // print 0 (aka val_1)
 }
```

Comment: I just presented an example. The real code I am working with is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @Lezkus - I see... Well, I suppose you should propose a minimal example that show how to get the error

Comment: I edited the question with the actual use case. I though that the formulation with any other type would be equivalent, but apparently it is not.

Comment: @Lezkus - answer modified to use `My_enum`

Comment: I see, that's a very good point. Does this generalise to a situation like this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190790/linking-against-a-shared-library-with-explicitly-instantiated-templates
?

Comment: @Lezkus - I suppose you can define `static constexpr const char charsStr[] = "chars";` as global constant and inherit from `std::integral_constant<char const *, charsStr>`

Answer (score 0):

This will cause linker error:

```
std::cout << &is_void<void>::value << std::endl;
```

because you odr-use `value` - it means you want its address. I am not sure but this might also happen with references - as they might be implemented internally as pointers. So until c++14 you would have to define your `value` inside implementation file.

Since C++17 you can use inline variables to keep it all in one place even if you need to odr-use it:

```
template< typename T > 
struct is_void{ 
  inline static const bool value = false;
  ^^^^^^ 
};
```