# constexpr: definition and declaration for constexpr members

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, constexpr

If I want to use some convenience stuff like `make_array` I have no chance to declare my array first and later make the definition as done in "earlier" times because the type of my var is not available before definition.

So I found this answer:
[Undefined reference to static constexpr char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char)

In the following example I wrote this solution which compiles fine with gcc and I am not sure that this is really valid c++ code, because it is more or less a declaration with definition and later a definition without any content. Is this allowed? ( Compiles fine is not a guarantee that the code is valid c++ )

```
#include <experimental/array>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    private:
    static decltype(auto) constexpr Bar =
        std::experimental::make_array(
            std::experimental::make_array( 1,2,3 ),
            std::experimental::make_array( 4,5,6 )
            );

    public:
    using ARR_TYPE = decltype( Bar );

    static auto& GetArr( int idx )
    {
        // range check ...
        return Bar[idx];
    }
};

constexpr Foo::ARR_TYPE Foo::Bar;

int main()
{
    for ( auto el: Foo::GetArr(0))
    {
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules governing `static constexpr` members changes in C++1z, which is kinda annoying.

### Pre C++1z

From [[class.static.data]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.static.data#3)

> [...] A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [...] **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used** ([basic.def.odr]) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

Which means you are **required** to provide a initializer in the declaration, but also to provide a definition at namespace scope **without** an initializer.

Your code does exactly that.

### Post C++1z

From the same paragraph [[class.static.data]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#3)

> [...] If the member is declared with the constexpr specifier, it **may be redeclared in namespace scope with no initializer** (this usage is deprecated; see [depr.static_constexpr]). [...]

And from [[depr.static_constexpr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.static_constexpr)

> For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a constexpr static data member may be redundantly redeclared outside the class with no initializer. This usage is deprecated.

So, this is still legal, but deprecated.

It should be noted `static` but not `constexpr` members (including `static const` members) are still required to have a definition in namespace scope if it is odr-used.

Comment: Very good to hear that we no longer need the redeclaration! I checked with gcc 7.1.0/C++17 and yes, I simply can remove the definition. So I will switch all my projects to c++17 :-) The language moves the right way!