# Defining constexpr static data members

Tags: c++, class, c++11, static, constexpr

So, I'm aware that in C++ static members can be initialized inside the class if they are a const literal type like the following

```
class test{
public:
        static constexpr int stc = 1;
private:
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
};
```

and the static constexpr variable `stc` can be used where the compiler can directly substitute the value of the member i.e

```
int main () {int array[test::stc];}
```

However, if used in a context where  the value cannot be directly substituted by the compiler:

```
int main() { const int &cs = test::stc; }
```

then the compiler (clang) generates an error

```
c++ -std=c++11 -pedantic    t.cpp   -o t
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::stc", referenced from:
      _main in t-a8ee2a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

unless the static member is defined outside the class like so:

`constexpr int test::stc;`

Why is this the case?

Comment: Which compiler are you using, what compiler error are you getting, and what is the minimal but complete code which triggers that error?

Comment: @MárioFeroldi updated post with more details

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question: [Why does a static data member need to be defined outside of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749071/why-does-a-static-data-member-need-to-be-defined-outside-of-the-class)

Comment: `const &cs...` gives an error: `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cs' with no type [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [constexpr: definition and declaration for constexpr members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721729/constexpr-definition-and-declaration-for-constexpr-members)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
int main() { const int &cs = test::stc; }
```

`test::stc` is odr-used while in

```
int main () {int array[test::stc];}
```

it is not.

The following example from [the C++11 Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2) supports the above idea.

> ```
> struct S { static const int x = 0; };
> const int &f(const int &r);  
> int n = b ? (1, S::x)    // S​::​x is not odr-used here
>           : f(S::x);     // S​::​x is odr-used here, so a definition is required
> ```

Looking at it from practical point of view, `cs` will be an invalid reference unless `test::stc` has an address. `array`, on the other hand, needs just the value of `test::stc`, which can be evaluated at compile time. `array` does not need the address of `test::stc` to be a valid object.

An object that is odr-used must be defined exactly once in a program.

Comment: Good one. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630570/what-does-it-mean-to-odr-use-something

Answer (score 2):

```
static constexpr int stc = 1; // declares the static var

constexpr int test::stc; // defines the static var
```

for more detailed explanation check link below

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/

Answer (score 2):

**C++17 `inline` variables**

In C++17 if you also mark the static member as `inline`, then I believe that you can odr-use it freely or have multiple definitions across compilation units, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
    public:
        inline static constexpr int i = 42;
};


int main() {
    const int &cs = MyClass::i;
    std::cout << cs << std::endl;
    std::cout << &MyClass::i << std::endl;
}
```

More info at: [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work/53896763#53896763)