# constexpr array member with template specialization: inconsistent behavior cross compilers

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, clang++, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct foo {};

template<>
struct foo<int> {
  static constexpr char value[] = "abcde";
};

template<class T>
struct bar {
  static constexpr char value[] = "abcde";
};

template<class T>
struct baz {
  static constexpr int value = 12345;
};

int main() {
    char c = foo<int>::value[2];
    char d = bar<int>::value[2];
    int e = baz<int>::value;

    std::cout << c << d << e << "\n";
    
}
```

When compiling with: `clang++ -std=c++14 ./test_foo.cc`, I got linker error for undefined symbols: `bar<int>::value` and `foo<int>::value`. When I change to `clang++ -std=c++17`, then only one undefined symbol: `foo<int>::value`. My clang++ version is 5.0.

However, when I tried `g++ -std=c++14 ./test_foo.cc`, compile succeeded. My g++ version is 5.4.0.

I have precisely 2 things to ask.

**1) From the C++ standard viewpoint, which compiler behaves correctly ?**

I have googled and read many cppreference pages, but haven't found anything really related to this phenomenon. Especially for the clang++ with `-std=c++17`, the behave is really bizarre, since `bar<int>` got passed but `foo<int>` failed, the only difference is that `foo<int>` is a specialization. And I read from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr that

> A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline.

Thus there seems no reason for template specialization `foo<int>` to fail. Furthermore, I looked at the generated object file before linking, the access to `foo<int>::value[2];` is *not* done at compile time as one would expect it to be. I highly suspect there is something wrong in the clang++ compiler.

**2) How to deal with this clang++ linking error ?**

I tried something like [Undefined reference to static constexpr char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char), but finally I couldn't find any way to overcome this linking error. So I just wonder whether there is a way to get this linking succeed.

Comment: Compiles fine with Visual Studio 2017 - oddly enough, even without specifying C++14/C++17 explicitly.

Comment: @CookiePLMonster g++ also succeeded to compile for for -std=c++11. But for clang++, the c++11 error can be avoid by the trick mentioned in the link above. However, the c++17 version I can't even find a way to make it compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until C++17, the reason is exactly the same as what stated in [the question you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char) (I think the answer posted by Shafik Yaghmour explains this problem more exactly). In short, the definition of a `constexpr` static data member is still required if the member is [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use).

You can [resolve the problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IkBwrOkcHiRRHJoW) by providing definitions of these variable **until C++17** (i.e. using `-std=c++14`).

---

Since C++17, the current standard in [[dcl.constexpr] paragraph 1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1) says

> ... A function or static data member declared with the `constexpr` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline]).

and in [[basic.def] paragraph 2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2) says

> A declaration is a *definition* unless
>
> - ...
> - it declares a **non-inline** static data member in a class definition ([class.mem], [class.static]),
> - ...

So such definitions at namespace scope are not required.

In addition, the current standard in [[depr.static_constexpr] paragraph 1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/depr.static_constexpr#1) says

> For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a constexpr static data member may be redundantly redeclared outside the class with no initializer. This usage is deprecated. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   static constexpr int n = 5;  // definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
> };
>
> constexpr int A::n;  // redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So you'd better avoid such definitions since C++17.

> When I change to `clang++ -std=c++17`, then only one undefined symbol: `foo<int>::value`.

It is a Clang bug. Anyway, it [works well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FrHufggNun6COGBP) for Clang HEAD 7.0.0.

Comment: So to summarize: 1) Because `bar<int>::value[2]` is an ODR-use, g++ accepts this template code in `-std=c++14` is technically a bug. In the linked question above, that code without template use is correctly rejected. 2) clang++ 5.0 cannot figure out template specialization case in `-std=c++17` is clang++'s bug. Thanks for providing these up-to-date details.

Comment: @liliscent In addition, `bar<int>::value[2]` is no more an odr-use after [CWG 1926](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1926).