# Why can't a static constexpr member variable be passed to a function?

Tags: c++, inline, c++17, constexpr, static-members

The following code produces an `undefined reference to 'Test::color'`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Color{
    int r,g,b;
};

void printColor(Color color) {
    //printing color
}

class Test {
    static constexpr Color color = {242,34,4};
public:
    void print(){
        printColor(color);
    }
};


int main() {
    Test test;
    test.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code produce the above error and what is the best way to avoid it, considering I want to use the latest version of the standard, C++17?

Should I define the static member variable, just like it was needed in earlier revisions of the standard (see the first answer here: [Undefined reference to static constexpr char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char)) or should I just create a new `Color` structure as can be seen below?

```
printColor(Color{color.r, color.g, color.b});
```

Edit:
I'm using CLion on Ubuntu 16.04, which as far as I could find out, uses g++ 5.4 for compiling. I have set it to use C++17 and still get the same error. The error is only present when `color` is passed to a function.

Comment: What's your compiler? That's a compiler bug if you did indeed compile your code with C++17.

Comment: I got the same error when I compiled with --std=c++14, but it worked fine with --std=c++17. I'm using gcc.

Comment: I'm using CLion with the default compiler on Ubuntu 16.04. I set the appropriate flag in my `CMakeLists.txt`  : `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`

Comment: Thanks, I think I got a little bit deceived by CLion then, because I could easily set it to use C++17, without a warning. But, as it seems, its default compiler doesn't even support it (fully..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was neither with the code itself, nor with the standard being used. CLion's default compiler does not fully support C++17, so that's why it showed a strange behavior that it could compile `static constexpr` member variables, but only as long as they were not passed to functions.

After updating to the most recent compiler version, I was able to run the code successfully without any changes.

Thank you for all your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that, before C++17, you had to specifically define the static variable outside the class:

```
class Test { 
   /* ... etc etc ... */
}

const constexpr Color Test::color;
```

The constexpr-ness of the static member does not let you 'waive' this explicit definition requirement.

With C++17, you no longer need to define static members explicitly. They are implicitly "inline" variables, which get auto-defined at some point, and just once per binary, without you having to take care of it. See [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf) for the long proposal of this feature.

Note that the definition must only appear in a *single* translation unit (so probably not in a header with class Test that gets included a lot).

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand it correctly, I can't pass an inline variable to a function at all, even in C++17?

Comment: @user3738870: No, that is in fact the *opposite* of what he said.

Comment: lol if you think that's a long proposal, wait til you see [Ranges](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r2.pdf)...

Comment: @NicolBolas But then what is causing the same error in C++17? And only when I attempt to pass it as a paremeter...

Comment: @user Your compiler fails to implement that feature yet?

Comment: @Barry: It's long relative to a StackOverflow answer.