# undefined reference to class static constexpr struct, g++ vs clang

Tags: c++, c++11, one-definition-rule

This is my code, a.cpp

```
struct int2
{
    int x, y;
};
struct Foo{
    static constexpr int bar1 = 1;
    static constexpr int2 bar2 = {1, 2};
};
int foo1(){
    return Foo::bar1; // this is ok for both clang++ and g++
}
int2 foo2(){
    return Foo::bar2; // undefined reference to `Foo::bar2' in clang++
}
int main(){ std::cout << foo2().x << std::endl; return 0; }
```

use clang to compile, `clang++ -std=c++11 a.cpp`

```
/tmp/a-0dba90.o: In function `foo2()':
a.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `Foo::bar2'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

`g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp` emits no error.

My question is,

1. who is right on the above code? clang or g++?
2. why bar2 is wrong while bar1 is correct in clang?

compiler version: g++ 5.4.0 and clang 7.0.0

UPDATE: The question is marked as a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char), but it is not. I know I could add explicitly definition outside class to get it pass for clang. This question is about why all the difference between g++&clang.

Comment: What type is int2? It is not in the standard.

Comment: @arorias  yeah, I included the definition.

Comment: @xdot: which version of clang? Cannot reproduce on godbolt from clang 3.0 onwards. https://godbolt.org/z/UwjgHv

Comment: Looks like a clang bug to me, unless the standard was broken back in C++11.

Comment: I could reproduce it with clang++ std=c++11 and std=c++14. No errors with std=c++17 and on g++. My versions are:clang 6.0.0 and g++ 7.3.0

Comment: @P.W Yeah! I also tried to reproduce on this website before I ask this question. I don't know why it fails on my local machine but clang in godbolt are happy with that. Anyway g++ 5.4.0 and clang 7.0.0 on my local machine.

Comment: @dave yes, c++17 fixed this, I just what to know why the difference before c++17

Comment: If a compiler either emits errors or doesn't depending on optimisation level, then this compiler has a bug *or* your program has UB.

Comment: Agreed, that's definitely not the duplicate of that question. Same subject, different question.

Comment: Not a dupe, totally different problem. Reopen.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to assume that if one compiler is right, the other one must be wrong. The program either contains an error (and then the compiler that accepts it is wrong) or it doesn't (and then the compiler that rejects it is wrong). This in turn relies on an implicit assumption that the error in question, namely, missing definition of an ODR-used entity, is a diagnosable error. Unfortunately it isn't. The standard explicitly states that:

> [[basic.def.odr/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10)] Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement; *no diagnostic required*.

As problematic and unwanted this provision of the standard is, it's there. Your program has undefined behaviour because of a missing definition, and an implementation is not required to diagnose it. So both compilers are technically correct at any optimisation level.

In C++17 with mandatory copy elision the program no longer contains any ODR-use of the variable in question constexpr static data members are implicitly inline, no separate deinition needed (thanks Oliv).

Comment: In C++17 constexpr static member variables are *inline* so copy elision or not the program is well formed in C++17. Whatsoever there are no copy elision here. The difference between GCC and Clang is that GCC never considers that trivial copy constructors odr uses the source variable (which is an extension to the language). It can be verified by replacing the body of `main` by `int2{Foo::bar2}`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question.

I have some vague understanding about [odr-use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

- For literal type Foo::bar1, it is not odr-used, so it is fine.
- For struct Foo::bar2: when return a struct inside a function body, it will invoke its copy constructor, which take a reference to `Foo::bar2`. So `Foo::bar2` is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program otherwise it will result a link error.

But why g++ does not complain? I guess it is related to compiler optimization.

Verify my guess:

1. copy elision

   add -fno-elide-constructors, `g++ -fno-elide-constructors -std=c++11 a.cpp`

   > /tmp/ccg1z4V9.o: In function `foo2()':
   >   a.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to`Foo::bar2'

   So, yes, copy elision will affect this. 
   But `g++ -O1` still get passed.
2. function inline

   add -fno-line, `g++ -O1  -fno-elide-constructors -fno-inline -std=c++11 a.cpp`

   > /tmp/ccH8dguG.o: In function `foo2()':
   >   a.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to`Foo::bar2'

Conclusion is both copy elision & function inline will affect its behavior. The different between g++ & clang is because g++ enabled copy elision by default but clang does not.

Comment: @geza it compiles fine when making a temporary variable in foo2(): `int2 foo2(){
    auto tmp = Foo::bar2;
    return tmp;
}`, so maybe its a clang bug invoking odr use on function return statement?

Comment: @phön: as odr-use violation is NDR, we cannot make conclusion, when a code successfully compiles. For your example, maybe clang elides the copy, that's why it compiles. But still, the copy constructor of `int2` odr-uses `Foo::bar2` (I'm considering pre-C++17 here). Here's what I think now: the first example compiles, because it indeed doesn't odr-use `Foo::bar1` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429108/copy-assignment-of-fundamental-types). But `Foo::bar2` is odr-used pre C++17. but if a compiler optimizes away copy constr, then we don't know about this.

Comment: @geza yeah i saw it compiling and rushed the comment. sorry. so the question is whether the copy of int2 does introduce odr usage. if it does, its okay to reject the code. but since int2 is super trivial i thought/think that it should be handled similar to the plain int. your linked question will answer that i hope