# Detect undefinded variable for msvc compiler for c++14

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, undefined-reference

Consider the following C++14 (it's important) code:

```
struct B {
    static constexpr int a = 1;
};

int main() {
    auto p = &B::a;
}
```

Being compiled with gcc it leads to "undefined reference" since `B::a` is not defined (just declared). To fix the issue we just have to define `B::a` outside the struct:

```
constexpr int B::a;
```

But I have a problem with msvc compiler. Even without definition of `B::a` the first code excerpt just compiled well (without an "undefined reference" issue).

Is there a way (I think a compiler option) to say msvc to detect such an issue being compiled for C++14 standard, i.e. when `/std:c++14` option is used?

Here is the link to godbolt where I've tested the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/G8BnFY

Comment: Is msvc wrong? I thought that the msvc behavior was now accepted as valid.

Comment: @Janosimas - in C++17. The question is about a C++14 codebase.

Comment: @Janosimas msvc is wrong. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28846608/3240681).