# How to have a static constexpr array in a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, static, constexpr

So I want to have a struct like this:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr int arr[10] = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    };
};
```

In which I have a static constexpr array.
If I try to access this array for example with this function:

```
int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%i ", A::arr[i]);
    }
}
```

It says I have an `undefined reference to 'A::arr'`.
How am I supposed to access this array?

I have tried using a getter function in the class like:

```
static constexpr int get(int index){
    return arr[index];
}
```

I also tried declaring an instance of the class, and accessing it through that:

```
A a;
printf("%i", a.arr[0]);
```

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/b8vhsW9re. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using the g++ compiler

Comment: try compiling with `-std=c++17`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28846608/4074081

Comment: May I ask why it doesn't work in lower versions?

Comment: You need a definition `const int A::arr[10];` in previous version, as not `inline`, as you ODR-use the member.