# Why does automatic type deduction not work for constexpr member referencing?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In the example code, compiled in C++17:

```
template <typename T = int>
struct A
{
    static constexpr double b = 0.5;
};

int main()
{
    A a;  // compiles
    double c = A<>::b; // compiles
    double d = A::b; // fails to compile
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8527cdbfa12c4eba)

`A::b` fails to compile because:

```
main.cpp:13:16: error: 'template<class T> struct A' used without template arguments
   13 |     double d = A::b; // fails to compile
```

I thought in C++17 automatic template type deduction would take care of this since I have the default template argument. What am I missing?

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: @kiner_shah compiled within catkin, so gcc with some ros version. Probably `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Comment: But the live example does it as well, and that is version: `g++ (GCC) 11.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instantiated class instance has own `A<T>::b` member.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T = int>
struct A
{
    static constexpr double b = 0.5;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << &A<int>::b << "\n"; 
    std::cout << &A<char>::b << "\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with clang++13 with the option `-std=c++17`. Output:

```
0x402008
0x402018
```

Think about if `A::b` could be compiled, which address would be selected by the compiler.

The live example https://godbolt.org/z/GqhjMvoz6

As for failed to compile `double d = A::b;` with the default template parameter, this is the rule, templates must be instantiated used with using angle brackets `<, >`.

Comment: Ok, from a technical point of view this makes sense, but when the compiler goes through, it will surely substitute the value in and there will  be no address right (At least in -O3 optimisation)?

Comment: The addresses still are different even with -O3. I suppose it comes from C++ until C++17 where definitions of static members were required, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char. Potentially it is possible, if the addresses of constexpr values are not requested, they are not present/placed in memory at all.